# Wordpress on localhost, wrong path to images

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost, filepath

after a great deal of time, I managed to set up my wordpress on localhost running xampp. The thing is now that I don't see any pictures or posts on my local copy. Via dev tools, I realised the path to the content looked like this:

> wordpress.localhost/wordpress.localhost/wp-content/...

If it wasn't for the doubled "wordpress.localhost", I'd be able to see it. What might cause this? Is this due to an error in the database? How do I fix it?

Thank you!

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have properly set your site name under the settings > General > Site Address : *http://wordpress.localhost*

Answer (score 1):

Images src must be like the following if images are inside your theme folder.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images-folder/image.png" alt="">
```

Change the image path as per your requirements.

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns your active theme path.